# is the possible to hide the CSS source code on Browser?

Tags: css

I want to hide the CSS source code and follow this tutorials but not working, could any pro help me check this error ? Thanks.
Code below:
Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function(){//Function call On Load windows

    $.post("Ajax.php?action=getCss",{},function(data){//Ajax Request To Css 
        $("#Corecss").html(data);// Paste css in Corecss Div without Shoing             
    });
 });//Thanks Hashaam zahid From Pakistan
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Corecss"></div>
```

ajax.php file:

```
if($_GET['action']=='getCss')
{
$sDbServerName="localhost";$sDbUserName="***";$sDbPassword="*****";$sDbName="Data";// Connection with database server $dbConnect=mysql_connect($sDbServerName,$sDbUserName,$sDbPassword);if($dbConnect)
{

      echo   '<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/creative.css" type="text/css">';


}
else
{
    die("You Cannot Do it With Css");
}


}//Thanks From Hahshaam zahid     ( ittuc.com )  and facebook/HashaamKhan321
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to hide the CSS used (or the source from where it was obtained) in browsers. Trivially, open up the "Network Tab" in the Developer Tools and monitor the fetched resources. Any 'errors' with the current code are unrelated to the [in]ability to hide CSS: and if the question is about a specific error, make such clear and *remove any unrelated questions*.

Comment: If anyone really wanted to look at CSS, they would most likely have a technical background and know how to find it. There are clever ways to hide things from newbies, but it won't work for all.